# Where is user settings file in Netbeans 6.5 on Vista?

Tags: java, netbeans6.5

I can't seem to find my settings file, where I can find my IDE Editir color settings file and save it ... So if I need to install NB on another machine I can just copy my settings from this machine to the new one. Or if my PC crashes and need to restore to factory setting, everything will be erased, but if I have this settings file, it will save me a lot of time every time I need to re-install NB. Does anyone know where it is ? On XP I know it's in "Documents and Settings", but in Vista there is no such a folder.

Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be in Users\\Documents  It might be in a subdirectory of NetBeans in there.